# Alarm clock for iPhone/iPad which permits me to choose custom sound track without apple music, exists?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ipados

I seek a simple alarm clock that permits me to choose an arbitrary soundtrack (mp3 file) from iPhone/iPad without messing with Apple Music/iTunes/etc..

- If a built-in HTTP server that can be used to upload the soundtrack from pc via browser, I will believe that this world still has hope for uncluttered apps that do one thing well.

Does this exist?

Answer (score -1):

The salvation came from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/iz6klz/alarm_clock_for_iphoneipad_which_permits_me_to/).
You can use the beautiful [iMazing](https://imazing.com/), it can sync items back and forth between devices without using [Apple's iBloat](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/aqvzur/any_good_alternative_to_imazing_for_transferring/egjyy6n?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)